mysql/vs2019: AllowPublicKeyRetrieval not appear in EF Model new connection properties
I have installed the next components to use Mysql in Visual Studio 2019 with .Net Framework 4.6.1 with .Net:

I am trying to create the conection using the properties I have in my connection string:

   server=xx.xx.xx.xx;
   ax Pool Size=1000;
   MinimumPoolSize=5;
   ConnectionReset=true;
   ConnectionLifeTime=0;
   user id=my_user;
   port=3306;
   password=xxxxxxx;
   SSL Mode=none;
   persistsecurityinfo=True;
   AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=true;
   Convert Zero Datetime=True;
   database=my_database

In the advanced properties I don't see AllowPublicKeyRetrieval property to set true because I am using SSL Mode as None.
I am getting this error:

It is nbormal because I have to set AllowPublicKeyRetrieval in the dialog properties and It doesn't appear:

how can i set AllowPublicKeyRetrieval to true?
Client reasons I can't change database with ALTER then it is just how to use this property
can you help me please?
